How to develop my own auto indent project on VS Code?
I am aware of many options of auto indent fix, or prettifying, for popular languages such as Python. My goal is to develop my own project to auto indent codes written in ECL, a language that has no support for it so far, and further provide it to the community as a VS Code.
Since I've never worked on anything like this, I just wanted to know which way should I go, if there is any SW or platform that would be helpful to me, and gather some developer experiences on this topic.
My first thought was to export the code as HTML, use tags to parse keywords and correctly apply tabs on it, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
